# Problemas con matches

Tags: java, regex

Quiero hacer una comprobación con matches, que compruebe que la cadena contenga 5 o mas caracteres que no sean ni la ñ, ni la z y tampoco la x.
He probado de la siguiente forma:

```
b=s.matches("\\w{5,}[A-z[^ñzx]][A-z[^ñzx]][A-z[^ñzx]][A-z[^ñzx]][A-z[^ñzx]]");
```

No funciona así, aclaro que `b` es una `boolean` y `s` es un `String` capturado en otra línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dependiendo del Motor de `Regular Expression` esta respuesta es diferente, recomiendo la lectura de esta pregunta en StackOverflow en ingles [Exclude characters from a character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327765/exclude-characters-from-a-character-class), donde dan varios ejemplos dependiendo del motor de `Regular Expression`. sin embargo dado a que segun la pregunta especifica es con Java. en este caso puedes utilizar esta `Regular Expression`:

```
"[\\w&&[^ñzx]]{5,}"
```

que de acuerdo a el [Javadoc de `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) indica:

`&&` se utiliza para la interseccion de dos grupos en este caso el grupo de `\w` y `[^ñzx]` (este ultimo excluye "*ñzx*"). por tanto:

`[\\w&&[^ñzx]]{5,}` es lo mismo que decir *incluya todo caracter de palabra* (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`) *exepto* `ñ,z,x`